# Run nginx as proxy for mongodb and proxy for a webservice running in tomcat

Tags: nginx, tomcat, mongodb

I want to run nginx to redirect requests to mongodb and a webservice both. I tried to use both server and stream directive but I was not able to get it right.

What should be the configuration file which I can use so that when I contact nginx server on 27017 port, I can access mongodb and when I access it on another webserver port, I should be redirected to the webservice running on tomcat.

Comment: You want to proxy all requests to MongoDB and proxy all requests to Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is with multiple `server` blocks, e.g.

```
server {
    listen 27017;

    proxy_pass <mongodb>;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    proxy_pass <webservice>;
}
```

Obviously `<mongodb>` and `<webservice>` should be replaced with whatever method you're using to connect to those services locally.